# How to say: "The film/series came out yesterday"

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request, expression, colloquial

Specifically, I want to know the correct verb in German for "to come out". It doesn't matter if the movie came out or the pastor is coming out sometime in the future.

I guess I can always say:

> Der Film wurde gestern veröffentlicht.

But I have a feeling that people would use some other expression for this while talking casually.

Comment: Der Film ist gestern rausgekommen. But you can't use that as a translation for every use of "come out" in English. There is rarely a one-to-one relationship between words in two languages.

Comment: I though so. "Rausgekommen" is what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: @Roland Your comment should be an answer because it's answering the question.

Comment: "the pastor is coming out sometime in the future" - could you elaborate what this is supposed to mean, in particular if you expect "veröffentlichen" is a valid, if formal, translation?

Comment: "Der Film kam gestern in die Kinos."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-colloquial phrase is:

> Der Film ist gestern in den Kinos angelaufen / seit gestern beim Streamingdienst verfügbar.

Both of those assumed, that the film is newly published, so the tense has to be adjusted accordingly for past/future.

Comment: Ich wollte „erscheinen“ vorschlagen, aber „anlaufen“ is spezifischer für einen Film.

Answer (score 2):

You can either say

> Gestern kam XY raus.

Or

> Seit gestern ist die neue Staffel (von) XY draußen.

Both are colloquial phrases.

Answer (score 1):

> Seit gestern läuft der Film (im Kino, beim Streamingdienst, ...).